# Do I need to reset the JFrame default close operation after each dispose/pack?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
0 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)
1 dispose()
2 pack()
3 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE) // is this needed?
```

Do I need to reset the JFrame default close operation after each dispose/pack?

Comment: ["Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to reset the JFrame default close operation after each
>   dispose/pack?

not, you need to declare, change this status only one time for concrete `JFrame`